# Advise users not to delete their question when it is closed as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Background: having duplicates around is not bad. It is even useful, e.g. easier to find the original due to the additional key words, etc.

That said, I see many users delete their question shortly after it's being closed as duplicate, e.g. [latest example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286063/i-want-to-send-images-in-mobile):

> [image]

In this example, having it stick around would, for example, have "send images in mobile" find the original request, where now [it does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=send+images+in+mobile).

So, my suggestion is as follows: when  a user click the "delete" link on their question, and it is:

- Closed as duplicate
- Non negative score

Then a confirmation dialog will appear advising the user to not delete, explaining why. There will be a button "Delete Anyway" of course, but I want to believe this will prevent quite a few deletions of possibly useful  contents.

Comment: Possibly an upvote would have made the user believe that their question has some worth, and a comment linking to why duplicates are not deleted by the community would be an added bonus. Hmm, I see the latter you have proposed as a feature request.

Comment: Or posting an answer which explains why the question is a duplicate, if the answer is upvoted, the OP cannot delete their question. I wouldn't bother for questions that are very poorly constructed, and illegible because they are utterly ungrammatical.

Comment: @Mari correct about upvote, but not always I feel it is proper to upvote. Sometimes I do upvote duplicates, it's really specific to each question. As for comment linking to why duplicates are not deleted, not sure what you mean? Last but not least, answer explaining why it's a duplicate will be a bad idea, that's not what answers are for.

Comment: The answer  would include the link to the older question, and perhaps a few  clarifying notes where admissible.*As for comment linking to why duplicates are not deleted* = I was thinking of Jeff Atwood's post about duplicates [How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)