# Don't put "Delete question" under the close banner

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, closed-questions

When a question has been marked a candidate duplicate and I accept it as a duplicate, the resulting banner includes an option to "Delete question".  (Moreover, this is marked in red, further highlighting that option.)  I am concerned this is sending the wrong message to people whose question is marked as a duplicate, or who accept that their question is a duplicate.  Including this option suggests that deleting is something that should be considered or is often appropriate.

We don't want people to delete their question just because it was a duplicate. Duplicates are usually useful to retain, because they help others find a resource via search.

I propose that the "Delete question" option should be removed from the banner.  The option already exists under the question; there is no need to highlight it in the banner.

[image: close banner when accepting a duplicate suggestion]

Comment: I've requested this here: [Remove the Delete Question button in the post notice for post authors when their question is closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350810/remove-the-delete-question-button-in-the-post-notice-for-post-authors-when-their)

Comment: @Spevacus, Excellent, thanks for finding that!  I searched but didn't find your post, so thank you for pointing me to it!